# Why are lp-lp repulsions greater than bp-lp and bp-bp?

Tags: molecular-structure, vsepr-theory

My teacher told me that lone pair and lone pair are closer together hence the repulsion is greater and they take up more space, but I do not understand? Can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 14):

So, from [Wikipedia article on VSEPR theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSEPR_theory) we read:

> The overall geometry is further refined by distinguishing between
>   bonding and nonbonding electron pairs. The bonding electron pair
>   shared in a sigma bond with an adjacent atom lies further from the
>   central atom than a nonbonding (lone) pair of that atom, which is held
>   close to its positively charged nucleus. VSEPR theory therefore views
>   repulsion by the lone pair to be greater than the repulsion by a
>   bonding pair. As such, when a molecule has 2 interactions with
>   different degrees of repulsion, VSEPR theory predicts the structure
>   where lone pairs occupy positions that allow them to experience less
>   repulsion. Lone pair-lone pair (lp-lp) repulsions are considered
>   stronger than lone pair-bonding pair (lp-bp) repulsions, which in turn
>   are considered stronger than bonding pair-bonding pair (bp-bp)
>   repulsions, distinctions that then guide decisions about overall
>   geometry when 2 or more non-equivalent positions are possible.

As I said in my comment, the key point is given in the second sentence: the bonding pair shared in a bond *lies further* from the atom than a nonbonding pair of that atom which is held close to its positively charged nucleus. Consequently, lone pairs are closer to each other than any other combination of pairs (lone pair-bonding pair and bonding pair-bonding pair), and thus, repell each other more strongly.

Comment: so the stronger repulsion will make them stay further apart and occupy more space too?

Comment: @XQ.Matsci, yes. Stronger repulsion -> bigger spatial separation.

Answer (score 9):

Simply put: a lone-pair orbital is "fatter" than a bonding orbital as I have [illustrated here](http://molecularmodelingbasics.blogspot.dk/2009/07/ammonia-vsepr.html).  This can be rationalized as follows: in a bonding orbital the electron pair is mainly attracted to 2 different nuclei which helps localize the electron pair.  In a lone-pair orbital the electron pair is mainly attracted to a single nucleus and can therefore spread out more without reducing this attraction.

Comment: Why does being attracted 2 different nuclei help localize the electron pair?

Comment: For example in $\ce{H2}$ the point that is closest to *both* nuclei is the bond midpoint, i.e. the middle of the line connecting the two nuclei.  This point will have the lowest electron-nuclear attraction energy and if you move away from that line this energy will increase.  Thus, the electron pair will tend to localize between the atoms.