# Lone pairs are more spread out, but how does this increase repulsion?

Tags: bond, valence-bond-theory, vsepr-theory

Both lone pairs and bonding pairs consist of 2 electrons.

From my understanding, bonding pairs are localised between two atoms and thus lie further from the nucleus, and have a longer sausage shape. Lone pairs are attracted to a single nucleus, and thus can spread out more, creating a rounder shape.

Now repulsion, is really determined by couloumbs law. Both lone pairs and bonding pairs have the same charge, so it must come down to distance. Does being more spread out mean, that at a particular instance, the distance is less, thus the repulsion larger? After all the shapes of bond, only create a probablistic area where electrons may be found at an instance.

My question then comes down to, how can we use the fact that the electrons are more spread out and closer to the nucleus in a bonding pair to explain why the repulsion is greater? Just because the former is true, I struggle to immediately conclude that the repulsion is larger. So can we use the former and coloumbs law to clarify this. Repulsion must be determined by coloumbs law right?

Comment: You struggle right and it isn't easy. It is a postrationalisation of vsepr shoehorned into valence bond theory. There are attempts to use the Pauli Principle for this, but that is really hard to explain. And I'm not sure it is the truth either.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32211/why-are-lp-lp-repulsions-greater-than-bp-lp-and-bp-bp https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/157867/quantifying-location-and-volume-of-lone-pairs-for-vsepr

Comment: "Repulsion must be determined by coloumbs law right?" Not really, it's more likely related to Pauli exclusion, mentioned earlier.

Comment: Bonds are of Lower energy that implies that the electrons are Closer to the 2 nuclei than the nonbonded electrons were to their individual nuclei. Take your thoughts one at a time and think them thru. There is so much volume about an atom or in a molecule if the bonds take up less space the nonbonded are free to take up more space and of course the inner electrons are repelling everyone. Things happen the charge explains it but use some common sense. The diffuse unshared pair pushes the bonds or the more compact bonds make space for the unshared pairs or both acting in concert.

Comment: I don't believe it is clear what repulsion you're talking about. The two electrons repelling each other? The net repulsion?

Comment: You make contradictory statements: "how can we use the fact that the electrons are more spread out and **closer to the nucleus in a bonding pair** to explain why the repulsion is greater?" and "**bonding pairs** are localised between two atoms and thus **lie further from the nucleus**, and have a longer sausage shape"

Comment: "Does being more spread out mean, that at a particular instance, the distance is less, thus the repulsion larger" This is very confusing. Less spread out would bring the electrons more close together and thus they would repel more.

Comment: Please check your statements, as it stands this risks being closed as unclear.